# Powershell Won't Exit After Running Cmd.exe

Tags: vba, windows, powershell, ms-access

I'm using powershell to

1. Close Access Database,
2. Download updated Access front end to local machines,
3. Update (overwrite) local documents, and
4. Launch the Access database with parameters using `cmd.exe`.

Everything works fine, but the `Exit` command doesn't work after using `cmd.exe` command to launch the database.

If I comment out the `cmd.exe` command, then the `Exit` command works just fine. But if I use the `Exit` command, the script stops there and the `Exit` command does not work. Below is the entire code that I'm talking about.

```
## Close Microsoft Access
Stop-process -name MSACCESS -Force

## Download updated Access database to local machine
Copy-Item "F:\New_DB\Win7DBDocs\WC_Sys.mdb" -Destination "C:\DB_Docs" -Recurse -Force

## Copy Documents and Spreadsheets to local machine
echo "Overwriting files C:\DB_WPDocs"
Copy-Item -Path "F:\New_DB\DB_WPDocs\*" -Destination "C:\DB_WPDocs" -Recurse -Force

## Launch Microsoft Access with Parameters
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\DB_Docs\WC_Sys.mdb" /WRKGRP "F:\DB_Docs\Secured.mdw"

Exit
```

Comment: I would say that forcing a close on users applications when they could be midway through something is probably a bad idea, leading to half completed records, and possible corruption. Far better would be to use a shortcut that runs the copy and then launches the application. This means that each time they open the database they have the latest version copied over from the server (and this version should have been compacted to improve performance).

Comment: The users themselves will call this script from VBA on their own local front-end of the Access database by pressing a button that says "Access Update".  From time to time I push updates to the front-end and issue a company-wide notice to update their application. They understand the button will close the Access application, run the update, then open again on their machine. Also, updates automatically run on Network login script, so they're covered either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.exe` will block until `MSACCESS.EXE` exits.

To make `cmd.exe` launch the program and return immediately, use the `start` command:

```
cmd.exe /c start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\DB_Docs\WC_Sys.mdb" /WRKGRP "F:\DB_Docs\Secured.mdw"
```

... or drop `cmd.exe` completely and use the `Start-Process` cmdlet instead:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" -ArgumentList "C:\DB_Docs\WC_Sys.mdb", /WRKGRP, "F:\DB_Docs\Secured.mdw"
```